# What is the corresponding function for corrmtx (in MATLAB) in Python?

Tags: python, matlab

I'm translating some code from MATLAB to Python and I'm stuck with the [corrmtx()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/corrmtx.html) MATLAB function. Is there any similar function in Python, or how could I replace it?

Comment: Maybe this: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html ?  This is just an attempt to Google it, I don't know anything about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spectrum` package has such a [function](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/software/spectrum/html/user/ref_others.html#spectrum.linalg.corrmtx).

Comment: Where can i download that package? Just couln't find it

Comment: There's is not a version for windows? It seems like that there's just the linux version.

Comment: This is the source version. Compiling on Windows should be possible, too.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html

The matlab docs for `corrmtx` state:

> X = corrmtx(x,m) returns an (n+m)-by-(m+1) rectangular Toeplitz matrix
>   X, such that X'X is a (biased) estimate of the autocorrelation matrix
>   for the length n data vector x.

The scipy function gives the Toeplitz matrix, although I'm not sure if the implementations are identical.

Comment: Ye I'm not sure about that too and I don't really know the theory behind those

Answer (score 0):

Here is a list of alternatives that can help you in translating your code, all of which contain that function:
[scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/) ([toeplitz](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) | [corrmtx](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html))
[spectrum](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/software/spectrum/html/genindex.html) ([corrmtx](http://thomas-cokelaer.info/software/spectrum/html/user/ref_others.html#spectrum.linalg.corrmtx))

The following is a link to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/643699/how-can-i-use-numpy-correlate-to-do-autocorrelation) that tells you how to use numpy for the auto correlation since it seems to be the default funcationality of [corrmtx](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/signal/corrmtx.html)

Additional Information:
[Finding the correlation matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437513/finding-the-correlation-matrix)
[Unbiased Estimation of Covariance Matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1781/unbiased-estimation-of-covariance-matrix-for-multiply-censored-data)

Comment: This looks like a syntax highlighter and nothing more.